Legend not matching scale_size_area when plotting sf objects
I have three spatial layers as sf objects in the same projection - two line layers and one dot layer. I want to plot the dot area as proportional to their value.
I have had some success, but with the third layer (dots, data frame name 'x') I cannot get the legend to match the aesthetics in the plot. The legend is producing square symbols of a single size, while the plot is producing proportional area dots.
Code:
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = track, color = "orange", lwd = 1.4) +          # line
  geom_sf(data = SZ_cropped, color = "grey40", lwd = 0.5) +     # line
  geom_sf(aes(size = total), data = x, color = "black", alpha = 0.7, shape = 21, fill = "purple") +      # dots
  scale_size_area(name = "Count") +                              # proportional area dots



I have also tried to over-ride the legend aesthetics this way, which still produces the exact same map and legend:
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = track, color = "orange", lwd = 1.4) +          # line
  geom_sf(data = SZ_cropped, color = "grey40", lwd = 0.5) +     # line        
  geom_sf(aes(size = total), data = x, color = "black", alpha = 0.7, shape = 21, fill = "purple") +      # dots
  scale_size_area(name = "Count", max_size = 5) + # proportional area dots
  guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21, fill = "purple", color = "black"))) 


I have played around with various aesthetics in the dot layer and legend but cannot figure this out. I wonder if it has to do something with plotting sf objects?
For reference, all layers are in EPSG:3005 projection.

It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data shared using dput(). I tried with the default example from geom_sf but wan't able to reproduce your issue: https://i.sstatic.net/MBSvEdIp.png

I was only able to replicate your problem when the point data was multipoint geometry.  Is it possible that you "x" data is in multipoint? If I supply similar 3005 projected line a point data your same plotting code it works as you expect.

Could not reproduce your issue either, even as a multipoint as @BEVAN suggested. Try x <- data.frame(lon = runif(20, -132, -123), lat = runif(20, 48, 54), total = sample(50:250, 20)) %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>% st_transform(3005) then ggplot() + geom_sf(data = x, aes(size = total), color = "black", alpha = 0.7, shape = 21, fill = "purple"). Does your issue persist? What versions of sf ,  ggplot2, and R are you using?

You could try using geom_sf() with key_glyph = "point" to force the glyph that is being used.
